# multithreading program with webrequests c#

Tags: c#, multithreading, webrequest

I want to make multithreading asynchronous download manager. But i have problems with multithreading.
One thread correctly works, but when I create second thread - works nothing.
I assume that a problem with synchronism of webrequest. I read this answer [Multithreading a large number of web requests in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4277844/multithreading-a-large-number-of-web-requests-in-c-sharp), but I didn't understand completely. Now question:  How can I modify a code to use a multithreading(Thread, Threadpool).

class `DownloadableContent`:

```
{
    private string url { get; set; }
    private string path { get; set; }
    private Stream streamResponse { get; set; }
    private Stream streamLocal { get; set; }
    private HttpWebRequest webRequest { get; set; }
    private HttpWebResponse webResponse { get; set; }

    public DownloadableContent(string url, string path)
    {
        this.url = url;
        this.path = path;
    }

    public void Download()
    {
        using (WebClient wcDownload = new WebClient())
        {
            try
            {
                webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);                 
                webRequest.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
                webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();
                Int64 fileSize = webResponse.ContentLength;
                streamResponse = wcDownload.OpenRead(url);
                streamLocal = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None);
                byte[] downBuffer = new byte[2048];     
                int bytesSize = 0;
                while ((bytesSize = streamResponse.Read(downBuffer, 0, downBuffer.Length)) > 0)
                {
                    streamLocal.Write(downBuffer, 0, bytesSize);
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                streamResponse.Close();
                streamLocal.Close();
            }
        }
    }       
}
```

And class `main`:

```
DownloadableContent file = new DownloadableContent("url", @"path");  
Thread thread = new Thread(file.Download);
thread.Start();
```

Comment: Your code is very confusing. You're using `WebClient` *and* `HttpWebRequest`. As a result, you're making two requests for every URL. You should remove the `webRequest` and `webResponse`, and just use `WebClient`.

Comment: Very likely the reason you're having trouble is that you're not disposing of the `webRequest` and `webResponse` objects that you're creating. I know from experience that this often causes things to stop working after just a few requests. Since you're not using them, just remove them from your code.

Comment: I left in a code only `Webclient` , and now it works good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is worth for you to read Async programming
then take a look at this
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Net.WebClient_methods(v=vs.110).aspx
You have method to download thing asynchronously.
Also take a look at TPL and avoid threads
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717(v=vs.110).aspx

Probably reading a little more will help you avoid lots of headaches.

This is an easy example

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var urlsAndPaths = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    urlsAndPaths.Add("http://i.forbesimg.com/media/lists/people/lionel-messi_416x416.jpg","messi.jpg");
    urlsAndPaths.Add("http://sizzlingsuperstars.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/Cristiano-Ronaldo-2-480x309.jpg", "cristiano.jpg");            
    foreach (var kvp in urlsAndPaths)
    {
        var wc = new WebClient();
        wc.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(kvp.Key),kvp.Value);
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: thanks for answer, looks correctly, but program condition is "New Download in New Thread" (training task) using Thread and Threadpool. (two differents realizations)

Comment: This is tasks for novices in .NET :)

Answer (score 1):

The best advice that I can give for you, is to use TPL. It's one good library from Microsoft to manager threads. I had used this for a similar problems of yours in my code, basically I had to download 8000 urls, in the begin the normal process was taking 30 minutes. After I used this library, the same process was finished in 30 seconds.

TPL LINK

[Task Parallel Library (TPL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717(v=vs.110).aspx)

Please, get a look in the example:

[BookStore- GitHub](https://github.com/pedroafsouza/BookStore)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which version of the .NET framework you are using, you could take advantage of the Task class. You could do something like this

```
    foreach (var uri in myCollection)
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            try
            {
                using (System.Net.WebClient client = new System.Net.WebClient())
                {
                    client.DownloadFileCompleted += (o, args) =>
                    {
                        //Do something with the download
                    };
                    client.DownloadFileAsync(uri);

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //Do something
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you on .NET 4.5? The "new way" to do this is with `Task.WhenAll`, which gets your downloads going asynchronously and in parallel but allows the framework to decide if/when work should be scheduled to the thread pool.

```
var client = new System.Net.WebClient();
await Task.WhenAll(urls.Select(url => {
    var path = ?? // build local path based on url?
    return client.DownloadFileAsync(url, path);
});
```